# Random Freezes in Ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: monitor

My screen occasionally freezes, but it unfreezes after a second. During the freeze I can still hear audio, and whatever game is still running with ~60 fps. Freezing might not be the correct term, but I'm not sure what it's called.